# php regex or string check to make sure a variable contains specific characters

Tags: php, regex, string, validation

I need to make sure a variable that holds `product id` contains only specific characters.

For integer-only variables I'm using `is_numeric` to check.

But for a product id, the variable can contain only the following characters:

- many numbers [0-9]
- the characters - (dash) AND/OR _ (underscore)
- it can contain the letters "s" or "c" (but not together)

For example, this is valid: `c23_2308724208_9873208`, this is valid: `12-c53_09872807342`, this is valid: `s23_208320720`. But this is not valid: `12-2352'; SELECT * FROM administrators;`.

I could go into what the format of the variable is but I don't think I need that as long as I make sure that the variables consists of ONLY the above. All I want to do is put a check that would protect from SQL injections. So I don't think I need to care about the format, do I? I only want to make sure that the given characters `s,c,[0-9],[-,_]` can be found in the variable, and nothing outside of this range of valid characters.

### Edit

Based on someone's comment that the format be strictly followed, then the exact format is as follows:

- optional prefix of numbers and a dash (eg. 132-)
- necessary letter (either s or c) followed by some numbers, then an underscore, then some more numbers (eg. s234_23872084732)
- optional suffix of an underscore followed by yet more numbers (so the complete example for this case would be `s234_23872084732_201874018743`).

so if all optional things were there, it would be like `132-s234_23872084732_201874018743`, and if only necessary components were there, then `s234_23872084732`.

but as a technical point, why is it necessary to follow a strict regex? as long as I make sure only required characters are there, a SQL injection is impossible, right?

Comment: show us some examples

Comment: and what have you done up to now?

Comment: any example is not valid?

Comment: if it can contain only s or c then how can this be valid? `s23_20y8320720`

Comment: oh i'm sorry that's a typo i didn't notice - i'll remove the `y`.

Comment: please rethink your format. is ssss______________ valid? Or 1111111111111111111111111111111111111111111s_______________________? If you want to prevent SQLinjection then is the best technique to test if the input is applying a strict format. Hence, choose a format in which SQLinjection is not possible and that you can test using a regular expression.

Comment: @LoekBergman ok i've edited the question to specify the format.

Comment: did you try the pattern in my answer?

Comment: It is best practice for security issues what is allowed instead of preventing what all could be wrong. The first is what you want to have, all other things are what you not want to have. There are so many options using different encodings, you can not test nor prevent that. Therefor is the base rule when thinking about protection to only allow what you trust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

something like?

```
/^([0-9]+-|)[cs][0-9_]+$/i
```

Comment: I tried this: `s13524;` and your regex turned it valid. How come? if you didn't mention a semicolon, why did a semicolon go through? sorry i'm really bad at regex.

Comment: it doesn't match the semi-colon it only matches the part with numbers

Comment: is there anyway to make sure it invalidates anything *outside* the given range?

Comment: @user961627 no problemo.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
[0-9\-_]*[s|c]{1}[0-9_]+
```

- `[0-9\-_]*` matches digits , dash and underscore can be present or not (*)
- `[s|c]{1}` matches s or c (one should be present ({1}))
- `[0-9_]+` matches digits and underscore (at least one should be present (+))

Comment: I've just edited the question.

Comment: i saw that i why i've updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

you can try this too;

```
/\b([0-9\-_]+)?([s|c])([0-9\-_]+)\b/i
```

Comment: How should this be used? I'm doing `preg_match('/\b([0-9\-_]+)?([s|c])([0-9\-_]+)\b/i',$product_id)`, when I added the `g` I got that `g is unknown` error.

Comment: If I put a variable like this: `23-c234_2347823082'; SELECT * FROM TAB;`, then `preg_match` returns true!

Comment: yes it returns true and returns '23-c234_2347823082' only! because it matches with that